# Custom Spec File when creating RPM packing with Setuptools?

Tags: python, rpm

is there any way to use my own spec file when using setuptools and setup.py to create a RPM? I would like to find a way to install the scripts in my setup.py directory to /etc/init.d instead of the usual place that they are installed by RPM. I can't seem to find a command to let me use a custom spec file instead of the one setup.py generates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to specify a custom .spec file when building a SRPM with setuptools. Either create a source tarball and build the SRPM using the custom .spec, or create a source package, extract it, modify the .spec file, and rebuild it.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I shoulda figured, since I couldn't find much documentation about it. So since setuptools creates the source file too, I can just extract that, manually modify the spec file, repackage it, and use that?